# Something that is more general than matrix

Tags: matrices

A matrix has integer number of rows and columns. Is there such thing that is more general than it, instead of rows and columns, it has 'length' and 'width'. In other words it has infinite number of elements. But with similar operation with matrix (e.g. addition, non-commutative multiplication, transpose, determinant, etc).
Is there such concept in mathematics? What do we call that object?
Thank you

Comment: I think linear transformations is what you'd like to search.  Or linear functionals as well.

Comment: Also, tensors are thought to be a common extension